# Samba share fails in Ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I have configured samba to share my home directory with another user on Ubuntu machines but for some reason my user can not access the home directory.

Here is the configuration  from **/etc/samba/smb.conf**

```
[global]
    workgroup = NS2
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    server role = standalone server
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    dns proxy = No
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
[homes]
    comment = SHARE THE HOME DIRECTORY
    path = /home/test1
    read only = no
    #valid users = %S
    #valid users = @ubuntu
    valid users = test1
    guest ok = no
    browsable = yes
    #directory mask = 0755
    #create mask = 0644
    #force user = test1
```

**smbd, nmbd, winbind is running and stopped and restarted many times but do not fix the problem**

from the client machine  used this command to connect

```
smbclient //172.31.31.48/home/test1  -U test1`
but got the following error messages (also the same error show using smbstatus):
`Domain=[NS2] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

as suggested in askubuntu and ubuntu forums to make the directory (/home/test1) and its subcontents 755 which is done properly but does not fix the problem.

**here is the error log from the client machine**

```
[2016/03/30 23:21:44.748574,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4365(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/home failed. Permission denied
[2016/03/30 23:21:44.749460,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4346(process_usershare_file)
  process_usershare_file: share name home/test1 contains invalid characters (any of %<>*?|/\+=;:",)
```

Can someone guide me to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple things I would change, will try to explain my best:

- path = /home/test1 **<= With the default samba 'homes' configuration, you don't need to specify a path, since it will automatically map it to the corresponsing user's home.**
- valid users = test1 **<= I would change this value to %S, it will automatically map 'test1' home to '\\server\username'.**

This would give you a final [homes] section that looks like this:

```
[homes]
comment = SHARE THE HOME DIRECTORY
read only = no
valid users = %S
guest ok = no
browsable = yes
```

After doind theese changes, make sure to restart you services:

```
$sudo restart smbd
$sudo restart nmbd
```

Offcourse, you will also need to remove 'home' from your **smbclient** line, and will change to:

```
smbclient //172.31.31.48/test1 -U test1
```

Just tested this settings succesfully under Ubuntu 14.04.4 with the following samba version:

```
$smbstatus --version
Version 4.1.6-Ubuntu
```

=========================

You can also install a GUI for managing samba shares:

```
$sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
```

Regards,

Comment: One of the reasons  to include the path of Home directory is such that I had 4 valid users on that samba server machine. Using the  conf  mentioned in the question (using this `smbclient //172.31.31.48/test1 -U test1` ) I was able to access it from the client machine but using this `smbclient //172.31.31.48/home/test1 -U test1` I get the same error mentioned in the question .Could you please explain me why so? Since I had many users on the machine I tried to specify the exact users' home directory that to be shared. Sorry for not mentioning about multiple users in the question

Comment: Don't worry @bhordupur, however... The same configuration I gave you will apply for multiple users without specifying `home` on the `smbclient` line. Why? When you are using the default `[homes]` share that is built in on the samba conf, it will automatically do the mapping for all users, that's the `%S` value for. If you wan to specify full custom paths, specifically for each user, the method will change a bit; That will be leaving the `[homes]` share unconfigured and create new shares with your custom parameters separately, for example: `[share1], [share2], ...`.

Answer (score -1):

Samba works brilliant in Ubuntu, just right click and click on local share, it installs Samba but there is one caveat, in versions after 12.04 a bug has prevented libpam-smbpass from being installed automatically. Install it manually and reboot. Your other machine will see the folders and can access them as guest if you have enabled it in sharing configuration that pops up after folder share. Otherwise the one accessing has to specify username and password of the machine that he or she is accessing.

Comment: Sorry for being fuzzy with the question. I was running Ubuntu server in both machines .

Comment: and do you use GUI or CLI to access the files, have you installed libpam-smbpass?

Comment: I use CLI though . Yes, this was installed (**libpam-smbpass**)manually before I configured samba in ns2 machine for sharing.